# Autosize text in a paste pivot table object in PowerPoint with VBa

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I am trying to autofit the text in a pasted pivot table object in PowerPoint. I have successfully pasted the pivot table into PowerPoint, but can not figure out how to change the font size in the shape or even better to auto fit the font into the shape. Is this even possible? Here is what I've tried to just change the font..which didnt work.

```
Set ppShape = PPSlide.Shapes(2)
With ppShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font
    .Size = 16
    .Bold = True
End With
```

I am pasting the pivot table using PasteSpecial Default.I wonder if that has something to do with it.

```
PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial (ppPasteDefault)
```

Thanks!